# How to safely de-duplicate files encrypted at the client's side?

Tags: encryption

[Bitcasa](http://www.bitcasa.com/)'s claim its to provide infinite storage for a fixed fee.

According to a [TechCrunch interview](http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/18/bitcasa-explains-encryption/), Bitcasa uses client-side convergent encryption. Thus no unencrypted data ever reaches the server. Using convergent encryption, the encryption-key gets derived from the be encrypted source-data.

Basically, Bitcasa uses a hash function to identify identical files uploaded by different users to store them only once on their servers.

I wonder, how the provider is able to ensure, that no two different files get mapped to the same encrypted file or the same encrypted data stream, since [hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) aren't [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_function).

Technical question: **What do I have to implement, so that such a collision may never happen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most deduplication schemes make the assumption that hash collisions are so unlikely to happen that they can be ignored. This allows clients to skip reuploading already-present data. It does break down when you have two files with the same hash, but that's unlikely to happen by chance (and you did pick a secure hash function to prevent people from doing it intentionally, right?)

If you insist on being absolutely sure, all clients must reupload their data (even if it's already on the server), and once this data is reuploaded, you must check that it's identical to the currently-present data. If it's not, you need to pick a new ID rather than using the hash (and sound the alarm that a collision has been found in SHA1!)

Comment: Using multiple hash functions also greatly reduces collision chances. It's easy to find an MD5 collision these days, but much much much harder to find two files that'd simultaneously collide in md5 AND sha1, let alone md5+sha1+sha256+etc....

Comment: @Marc, rather than mixing hash functions ad-hoc, just pick a more secure function from the start like SHA512 (or, once it's standardized, SHA-3)

Comment: Defense in breadth - it's not unreasonable to assume that even SHA-3 (if/when it is standardized) can be completely broken. By using multiple hashes, you've still got safety margins that would be completely gone if you put all your eggs into that one single broken hash's basket. But yes, starting off with a good (as yet) unbroken hash initially is still a good idea.

Comment: Thx, @bdonlan. Just wanted to confirm, that no magic function has been invented, which could help here...

Comment: @SteAp It would have to be a reality-bending magic function to beat the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): if the function output has fewer bits than the input, potential collisions must exist.